# Код библиотечной функции retainAll

Tags: java

Подскажите, как выглядит код библиотечной функции в Java, а именно `retainAll`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

```
 public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
     return batchRemove(c, true);
 }

 private boolean batchRemove(Collection<?> c, boolean complement) {
     final Object[] elementData = this.elementData;
     int r = 0, w = 0;
     boolean modified = false;
     try {
         for (; r < size; r++)
             if (c.contains(elementData[r]) == complement)
                 elementData[w++] = elementData[r];
     } finally {
         // Preserve behavioral compatibility with AbstractCollection,
         // even if c.contains() throws.
         if (r != size) {
             System.arraycopy(elementData, r,
                              elementData, w,
                              size - r);
             w += size - r;
         }
         if (w != size) {
             for (int i = w; i < size; i++)
                 elementData[i] = null;
             modCount += size - w;
             size = w;
             modified = true;
         }
     }
     return modified;
 }
```